# GPIO Failed to create symbolic link. Operation not permitted

Tags: permissions, directory, symbolic-link

I'm trying to create a symlink to an existing gpio symlink in the `/sys/class/gpio/` directory, and I'm getting the following output:
`ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/gpio/MyLink': Operation not permitted`

I'm using the following command to create my symlink:
`sudo ln -s /sys/class/gpio/gpio447 /sys/class/gpio/MyLink`

I want the link to exist in the same directory of the original, but with a different name. Is this allowed?

Comment: Perhaps you better state what you really want to achieve (problem X) instead of asking about something (problem Y) you think will solve your actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/sys/class/gpio/MyLink': Operation not permitted` output, has to do with the `/sys/class/gpio` directory. Files created in `/sys` are all created by the kernel or drivers, thus the user cannot simply create new entries under that directory.